# ReferenceError: $ is not defined although jQuery was added in Layout.jade

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am getting this error when trying to run some basic JavaScript code in Node.js

```
 ReferenceError: $ is not defined                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/nodetest2/public/javascripts/global.js:5:1)                                                                                                                                          
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)                                                                                                                                                                                              
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)                                                                                                                                                                                
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)                                                                                                                                                                                        
        at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:441:10)                                                                                                                                                                               
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

In my Layout.jade I have added

```
     script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js')
     script(src='/public/javascripts/global.js')
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Any other scripts in page?

Comment: Are you connected to internet? That's also a possible case.

Comment: I am connected to the internet i am working on c9 env, i have global.js file that contains the javascript.

Comment: Just to be clear... this error is in browser not node console correct?

Comment: I get the error in the console , the browser seem to be fine how ever data is not loaded.